# Using ORDER By with DataNucleus Rest API and GAE Datastore

Tags: java, rest, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I'm successfully pulling back my objects however, I would like for them to already be sorted by a field in the object.

I have this working:

```
new Ajax.Request("/dn/com.emooney.meeting.beans.Meeting?groupName=='"+name+"'"
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
new Ajax.Request("/dn/com.emooney.meeting.beans.Meeting?groupName=='"+name+"'"&ORDERBY='day'
```

I've tried the following:
&ORDERBY=='day'
&ORDERBY==day
&ORDERBY='day'
&ORDERBY=day

Any ideas? I can't find any documentation on how to orderby when using DataNucleus's RestAPI.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code (which I didn't write) it only allows the WHERE clause currently. Guess you'd have to implement the ordering over at your side.